# Obtener valor de item en JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de "CreateTaskAllowed" dentro de "datos", el problema que tengo es que hago demasiados pasos para poder obtener el valor. Me podrían ayudar indicandome de que forma puedo hacerlo pero con menos codigo. Gracias

```js
const datos = {
    "gridViewConfig": null,
    "filterAttributes": "{\"CreateTaskAllowed\":true, \"DeleteTaskAllowed\": true}",
    "tabFilterAttributeValue": {
        "createTaskAllowed": true,
        "deleteTaskAllowed": true,
        "rangeDates": false
    }
};

const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(datos);
const parseado = JSON.parse(myObjStr);
const parseado2 = JSON.parse(parseado.filterAttributes);

console.log(parseado2.CreateTaskAllowed);
```

Comment: Tal como te dicen en la respuesta, `datos` es un objeto, por lo tanto no necesitas usar `stringify` a menos que quieras convertirlo en cadena. Donde sí debes usar `parse` es en la propiedad `tabFilterAttributeValue` que efectivamente es una cadena en formato JSON. Y recuerda JSON != Objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es que debes conocer la diferencia entre `JSON` y `Objeto` (no son lo mismo), el primero es un formato cuya estructura se asemeja muuucho a la estructura de cómo se declara un Objeto en javascript. La diferencia práctica en tu caso radica que un JSON es un `String` (está envuelto en comillas) , dicho esto:

- `const datos` es un Objeto, no hay necesidad de parsearlo
- `datos.filterAttributes` es un String con formato JSON, hay que parsearlo

Entonces:

```js
const datos = {
    "gridViewConfig": null,
    "filterAttributes": "{\"CreateTaskAllowed\":true, \"DeleteTaskAllowed\": true}",
    "tabFilterAttributeValue": {
        "createTaskAllowed": true,
        "deleteTaskAllowed": true,
        "rangeDates": false
    }
};

datos.filterAttributes = JSON.parse(datos.filterAttributes);
console.log(datos.filterAttributes );
```